# How to get the child element value using $event in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I am using the `$event.currentTarget` to get the element on `ng-click` as shown below:

```
<div ng-click="eventHandler($event)" class="bg-master m-b-10" id="slider-tooltips" nouislider=""></div>
```

In my controller when in console am getting:

```
<div ng-click="eventHandler($event)" class="bg-master m-b-10 noUi-target noUi-ltr noUi-horizontal noUi-connect" id="slider-tooltips" nouislider="">
    <div class="noUi-base">
        <div class="noUi-origin noUi-background" style="left: 9%;">
            <div class="noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower">
                <div class="tooltip fade top in" style="top: -33px;left: -14px;opacity: 0.7;">
                    <div class="tooltip-inner">
                        <span>9.00</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the value **9** in the above to show as result. How can I do this in AngularJS?

If this method is wrong, then please let me know the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried below code and i got the result which i was looking for

```
$scope.eventHandler = function($event){
  console.log(parseInt($event.currentTarget.childNodes[0].textContent));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if this is the best way to go about it, but you can get it from the click event. This worked for me:

```
$scope.eventHandler = function(e) {
    console.log(e.srcElement.children[0].firstElementChild.style.left);
};
```